# Вопрос про вывод бинарного файла

Tags: c++, binary-file

Задание: нужно создать бинарный файл и добавить в него 7 чисел

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a;
    ofstream FileOut("file.bin", ios::binary);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        cin >> a;
        FileOut.write((char*) &a, sizeof a );
    }
    FileOut.close();
}
```

Если ввести числа от 1-7, выводит [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так и должно быть? Или все же "00" между числами можно убрать?

Comment: Ну, если вы хотите записывать `unsigned char`, то можете убрать. А `int` — это все же 4 байта, а не 1.

Comment: Вы сами указали сколько байт записывать в вызове `FileOut.write`.